# Computing (or approximating) distribution of a compensated Poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, poisson-process

Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant0\}$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ and consider the compensated process $M(t) = N(t) - \lambda t$. It is well-known that $M(t)$ is a martingale. Is it analytically tractable to compute the distribution $\mathbb P(M(t)\leqslant s)$ for $s\in\mathbb R$? This is equivalent to $\mathbb P(N(t)\leqslant \lambda t+s)$, and the Poisson distribution does not have a nice closed form, so I have not had much success.

If not, can we reasonably approximate its distribution, perhaps for large $t$?

Comment: I'm also interested in the distribution of $\inf\{t>0:M(t)=0\}$ but that is a bit of a side question.

Comment: For all $s \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} P[M(t) \leq s] = 1/2$ by the central limit theorem.  Indeed note that for positive integers $k$ we have $P[N(t) < k] = P[X_1 + ... + X_k > t]$, where $\{X_i\}$ are the iid exponential inter-arrival times.

Comment: I can see $\mathbb P(M(t)\leqslant 0)\stackrel{t\to\infty}\longrightarrow\frac12$ but for all $s$? How does the CLT come into play when there is no sample average?

Comment: $$P[N(t)<k]=P[X_1 + ... + X_k > t] = P\left[\underbrace{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k(X_i-E[X])}{\sqrt{k}}}_{G_k}>\frac{t-kE[X]}{\sqrt{k}}\right]$$ where $G_k$ approaches a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance $Var(X_1)$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.  You can use appropriate values of $k$ and $t$ for your problem.  Note that this holds for any arrival process $N(t)$ with iid inter-arrival times with mean $E[X_i]$ and finite variance $Var(X_i)$ (not just exponentially distributed inter-arrival times).

Comment: I see. The characteristic function of $M(t)$ is also easily computed:
$$
\varphi(\theta) = \exp(\lambda t(e^{i\theta}-1-i\theta)).
$$